# Что такое инстанс (экземпляр) приложения?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Не смог найти конкретного объяснения что это означает **на практике**.
Раньше думал что это, грубо говоря, запущенный сервер (например, puma) или участок в памяти, на котором выполняется код, который обрабатывает запросы.
Тогда почему говорят что запущенно несколько инстансов приложения?
В контексте rails что отвечает за работу с инстансом приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рельсовые web-сервера (напр. таже [puma](http://puma.io)) могут работать в двух режимах:

1. single mode
2. cluster mode

В первом случае запускается один экземпляр puma-сервера, т.е. если придут два запроса, то они обработаются им последовательно, друг за другом.

Во втором случае запускается несколько экземпляров сервера (сколько - мы сами указываем в конфиге). При этом входящие запросы будут обрабатываться параллельно.

Это пояснение инстанса в контексте web-сервера, т.е. сколько его экземпляров запускаем.
Еще есть пояснение для хостингов (напр. того же самого [heroku.com](http://heroku.com)), но это отдельная история.